# What is the systemd-native way to manage NIC ring buffer sizes before bonded interfaces are set up?

Tags: systemd, network-interface, startup, ethernet, systemd-networkd

Managing NIC ring buffer sizes with ethtool is simple, for example:

```
ethtool -G eth0 rx 4096 tx 4096
```

(Or replace `eth0` with whatever interface you need to manage.)

Doing this live is easy.

Trouble is, when you do this on each slave interface that's part of a bonded interface, you mess up the bond.  (The aggregator IDs will in many cases not match up afterwards the way they do before.)  EDIT: I have learned this is not expected behavior.  (I may update when I learn more regarding why it happened in the case I observed.)

In RHEL 7, you can set the ring buffer size to come up at boot time by setting the `ETHTOOL_OPTS` value in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` to (for example) `ETHTOOL_OPTS="-G ${DEVICE} rx 4096 tx 4096"` (as per the [access Red Hat article](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2127401)).  (Caveat: I have not tested that this actually avoids the aggregator ID mismatch mentioned above.)

However, for Ubuntu 18.04, there is no such obvious easy place to look.

I've delved through netplan documentation, systemd network documentation, and networkd-dispatcher.

A colleague of mine came up with a solution using networkd-dispatcher that *seems* to work, but it's not clear whether there might still be race conditions involved such that it only *happens* to work, rather than being *guaranteed* to set the ring buffer sizes before the interface bond is set up.  I'll post this below (later on), but I don't know if it is THE correct answer.  (Also, it's not mentioned in any systemd documentation.)

So the question is:

**What is the systemd native way to manage ring buffer sizes for ethernet interfaces at boot-up time before those interfaces are bonded?**

Comment: Related on AskUbuntu: https://askubuntu.com/q/1175333/457111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The systemd native way to set parameters is with a `.link` file (see the [systemd.link manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man5/systemd.link.5.html), however it currently doesn't have a way to set the ring buffer parameters. So AFAIK there isn't a native systemd way to do this. This will change when a new systemd with [Wildcard's feature request](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/13601) is released with `RxBufferSize` and `TxBufferSize` options.

If you're actually using `/etc/network/interfaces` to configure, then just use a `pre-up` command there. This would be my preference instead of bothering with systemd-networkd.

You could set up some udev rules to match the device when it appears, and run ethtool there. This should run before systemd is informed about the device (and this before it does anything with it).

You could set up a systemd service (type oneshot, just exec ethtool) to run before whichever service sets up your bond device and after the device shows up, and use that. systemd makes `.device` units for Ethernet devices; use `systemctl list-units | grep sys-subsystem-net` to find the right one (so you can have your service be Wants/After it).

Comment: Thanks, I've opened a feature request upstream for systemd to make this possible in future versions: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/13601

Comment: Unfortunately, we're not using `/etc/network/interfaces` - it's Ubuntu 18, so we're using netplan, which doesn't support pre-up hooks.  There is a related question over at AskUbuntu: https://askubuntu.com/q/1175333/457111

Comment: When you say a udev rule "should run before systemd is informed about the device" — do you mean that's how it should work with no special attention, or that I should do something to configure it so it will work that way?  (I haven't used udev before, so a link to the documentation would be very helpful.)

Comment: And I'll see if I can find which systemd service sets up the bond; thank you for the tip!

Comment: @Wildcard I mean it should work that way with no special attention. I said "should" just because I haven't actually tested it.

Comment: Incidentally, my systemd feature request was accepted and implemented.  :)

Comment: @Wildcard thanks for the update. Feels weird editing that in to the answer, but it'll help anyone who stumbles across the question in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a udev rule that works on Ubuntu 18:

```
ACTION=="add|change", SUBSYSTEM=="net", KERNEL=="eth*|en*", RUN+="/sbin/ethtool -G $name rx 4096 tx 4096"
```

Put this in `/etc/udev/rules.d/59-net.ring.rules` and it takes effect early in the boot process.

Comment: I can confirm that this worked for us. On Ubuntu 18.04 (where https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/13601 is not yet available), this can be a reasonable approach.